# CassandraRepository with String returning value in query method

Tags: java, json, spring, cassandra, spring-data

I have a Spring application which requests data from a Cassandra data base. Usually, I specify convenient POJOs that I'm using in the query methods of the repository class as data model return result.

But in my current case, **I don't want a mapping into a specific model object. I want the query result as raw JSON string (or whatever as `Map`).**

According to following documentation I can request raw JSON by using `JSON` keyword in the CQL query: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryJSON.html

And theoretically, Spring Data JPA should support simple types as query results: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-introduction-to-query-methods/

```
@Repository public interface DataRepository extends CassandraRepository<String> {

  @Query(
     "SELECT JSON uid"
         + ", version"
         + ", timestamp"
         + ", message"
         + " FROM message_data WHERE uid=?0 ALLOW FILTERING")
  Optional<String> findById(UUID id);
}
```

But finally, I get a mapping error on Spring application's start up:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataController' defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/.../DataController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(CassandraRepositoryFactory.java:104) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

What am I missing here?

**SOLUTION:**

According to the accepted answer following code snippet did the trick:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder;
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select;

...
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;
...

private Optional<String> findById(final UUID id) {
  final Select select = QueryBuilder.select().json().from("message_data");
  select.where(QueryBuilder.eq(...))
        .and(QueryBuilder.eq("uid", QueryBuilder.raw(id.toString())));

  return Optional.ofNullable(cassandraTemplate.selectOne(select, String.class));
}

private void insert(final MessageEntity entity) {
  cassandraTemplate.insert(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataRepository` is extending `CassandraRepository<String>` which is a problem.

The `CassandraRepository` declaration goes like `CassandraRepository<T,ID>` where

```
T - the domain type the repository manages
ID - the type of the id of the entity the repository manages
```

In your case `T` would be `Entity/Table` class you are using for `message_data` table and `ID` would be `UUID`.

If you need to **run the query without Repository**, use `cassandraTemplate`:

```
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;
```

Comment: I tried to replace ``T`` by ``HashMap``. Start up succeeds, but now I get ``CassandraTypeMismatchException: Value 0 of type class [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node; does not correspond to any CQL3 type; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node; does not correspond to any CQL3 type] with root cause`` on trying to write ``HashMap`` into Cassandra.

Comment: @PAX `T` has to be the table class you are using... not the hashmap.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like to avoid model classes that represent Cassandra table entries. In my scenario, this isn't required and would increase maintenance costs if something changes in the table structure.

Comment: Thanks. Is it compatible with Cassandra? EDIT: Possibly http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandratemplate-cqltemplate would do the trick?

Comment: you're right... updated answer see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandratemplate-cqltemplate